# HP Smart Array P212 - rebuild Array 1 for OS without loosing Array 2 (Data)

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array, raid1

Ok.. I'm fairly new to this, but I have a DL180 G6 running with following configuration an HP's P212 Controller:

01 Array:  2x 1TB for OS

02 Array: 12x 2TB for Data

Now I would like to Change both Hard drives in 01 Array without dropping 02 Array.

First try.. creating an Image from OS and changing both Hard drives at the same time. That leaded to total loss of Array configuration Data.

I was luckily happy after inserting the old drives and rebooting the System, as everything was at it was before.

So again: How can I perform the exchange of both hard drives in 01 Array without losing configuration Data on HP’s P212, respective without losing 02 Array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. was easier then thought..:

1. Turn off Server.
2. Remove old drives (01 Array)
3. Go to Controllers GUI and delete (!) 01 Array
4. Shut down Server again.
5. Insert new drives (2 exact drives if u still want Raid 1)
6. Start Server and enter Controllers GUI
7. New drives will appear as Raid 1, if not creat new Array.

Thanks for help and constructive answers..

cu

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the drives in 01 Array. Replace it with the new disk. Allow it to rebuild.

Once it's done, repeat for the second drive.

Comment: Ok.. should have mentioned that the new drives are smaller (300GB, 2,5'' SAS) then the old once (1TB 3,5'' SATA)

That leaded to failure message and Controller refused to rebuld the Array.

Comment: Oh, I don't know about that. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Good question.. guess that we started with these old hard drives, just to see how it workes and the we got stuck to it. Now the old drives are getting really old (>6 years) and we just want to renew them.

We also thought about using SSDs for OS.

And.. before you ask.. we don't want to spend Money on new drives to make a backup (Data) in the first place. We just build up the Sytem two years ago.

But thanks anyway..

Comment: @Hermes76: Just to say the obvious: A RAID is **never** a replacement for a backup. If you don't already backup the data and it is important for you, invest the money to have a good, reliable (preferably offsite) backup. If you don't, consider the data as already lost.

Comment: As fare as I know.. this is not supposed to be a chit-chat.. right..

So thanks for your advice for backup up important data. But this was not my question. 

Anyone who is able and willing to give advise to the problem itself?

Comment: Yes. Just do it over. You're downsizing disks, so offload the data, configure the array the way you wish it to look, and repopulate the data.